# do I need to generate a new php file for every virtual page created by a site member?

Tags: php

I want the site member to create pages that are searchable by google and can be linked to. The intention is that comments and discussion would then take place on the newly created page.

```
For example
funfoods.com/getting-kids-to-eat-broccoli
funfoods.com/discovered-a-new-farmers-market
or
strategygame.com/game-94572yu34g
strategygame.com/game-05ww945t2j
```

Would I need to generate a new php file for every page created by the user? (I am hoping not to)

Or would it be something like showpage.php?argument but then how do I get it to show up as a meaningful url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what you're trying to do without getting more information on this "create pages" feature of yours.

What I would do is give the member the ability to create a page, obviously, and then maybe add this to the table your storing the information in:

```
tbl_member_site_pages: id, ..., pageTitle, pageURL, pageKeywords
```

You can SEO the pageTitle, pageURL, and pageKeywords respectably, and then do some fun with PHP and RewriteCond and RewriteRules

For the latter, check this out: [htaccess url rewrite/redirect - like facebook does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167871/htaccess-url-rewrite-redirect-like-facebook-does)

For the PHP, I would do something like this:

```
// assume strategygame.com/index.php?page=check-out-this-strategy-by-josh, or strategygame.com/check-out-this-strategy-by-josh
$page = $_GET['page'];
$result = $m->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_member_site_pages WHERE pageURL = '$page'");
// display page
```

Comment: Thanks Josh,  I'll take a look at RewriteCond and RewriteRules. Do you know any tutorial online that you can link to?

Comment: Hey bud: you know, I don't really. I don't do much of that myself either, so I can't exactly help you there. But if you want, you can shoot me an email as I'd love to be a resource and a helping hand for you in the future for questions like this. jbrody13[at]gmail if you please. :)

Answer (score 0):

You create one PHP file that will display different information based on the input parameters. To achieve "meaningful" URLs you'll need to do URL rewriting on your web server.

The correct term for this kind of URLs is "seo/user friendly URLs", there's plenty of information on the internet/SO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't generate a new php file for every page. Instead, you should keep data in the database and pull different records based on the URL. To achieve nice/clean looking URLs, you would use "slugs" such as "getting-kids-to-eat-broccoli". Finally, you would create .htaccess file that would redirect all requests to pages that don't exist on the server to your central php file that would extract slug from the requested url and try to match it against the database.