# How to get url the same as page title

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite

I wonder whether I can accomplish the following?

I have a dynamic webpage; the URL of a page is a result of a dynamic process.  And looks like `Mysite.com/cars/850#.RRptwXgg8`

The metadata is retrieved automatically and looks like

```
<meta name="title" content="Cheap Ford Taurus in Paris" />
```

How can I make it so the URL will look like:

```
Mysite.com/cars/Cheap-Ford-Taurus-in-Paris
```

Comment: Shouldn't be hard but depends on your "dynamic process", and how it generates a page, so you should add that code here.

Comment: Use the exist framework or make your own route should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Homes (homeslice),

I answered a similar question that looks to be relevant to your problem: [do I need to generate a new php file for every virtual page created by a site member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119242/do-i-need-to-generate-a-new-php-file-for-every-virtual-page-created-by-a-site-me/14119327#14119327)

Comment: thanks very much... reading a lot, the url was very importan 5 years ago an back, but now the botcrawlers are very intelligent an look for another thinks, like title, tags and words... google advice against url rewrite.... i.e look youtube.com its videos and its url s